# How to get accesstoken from WebClient like in RestTemplate?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-webflux

I was going through the Spring Security Oauth 2.x migration to Spring security 5.2 and encountered the following blocker.
As I can see `OAuth2RestTemplate` is not used anymore, instead `WebClient` is recommended. So i was making changes to my codebase to make webclient work.

In Oauth2 we have an option to get token straight from RestTemplate using `oAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken()`, i couldn't find anything similar in WebClient. This is to call an external microservice.
Is there any option to get the accesstoken from webclient? Or is it handled in a different way there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As usual when working with spring security, a lot of stuff happens automagically with configuration by convention. Meaning: you should get familiar with the oauth-related spring security configuration.

A good starting point for your studies will be the [spring security docu](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security) or one of the many good Baeldung articles on this topic (maybe this one helps: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-oauth-login-webflux).

With the correct configuration in place, the following method will create a `WebClient` that has the proper oauth token automatically created on demand in the filter method.

In this case a Bean of type `ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` takes care of this. That bean is created in listing no. 2.

Furthermore, you need to configure the oauth server url and the credentials. See Listing 3 for a simple example.

This example works without you needing to handle the access token.

```java
    @Bean
    public WebClient oauthWebClient(
        final WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder,
        @Qualifier("authorizedClientManager") final ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager manager) {
        final ExchangeStrategies exchangeStrategies =
            ExchangeStrategies.builder()
                              .codecs(configurer -> configurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(EXCHANGE_BYTE_COUNT))
                              .build();
        final ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(manager);
        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId(authenticationProperties.getClientId());
        // set more properties if needed
        // oauth.set ...

        return webClientBuilder
            .exchangeStrategies(exchangeStrategies)
            .baseUrl(apiProperties.getBaseUrl())
            .filter(oauth)
            .build();
    }
```

**Listing 1: create a WebClient bean**

```java
    @Bean
    public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
        final ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
        final ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {
        final ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
            ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder
                .builder()
                .clientCredentials()
                .build();
        final AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
            new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);
        return authorizedClientManager;
    }
```

**Listing 2: create an OAuth2 authorized client manager bean**

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://your-oauth-server.com/auth/realms/your-realm
      client:
        provider:
          your-provider:
            issuer-uri: https://your-oauth-server.com/auth/realms/your-realm
        registration:
          your-provider:
            client-id: your-client-id
            client-secret: ${your_client_secret} # from an environment variable
            scope: openid
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
```

**Listing 3: one of many possible ways to configure your spring web client**

Answer (score 1):

Check if this helps

```
public String getToken() {

return webClient
    .post()
    .uri(uri)
    .body(
        BodyInserters.fromFormData(GRANT_TYPE, PASSWORD)
            .with(USERNAME, userName)
            .with(PASSWORD, password)
            .with(CLIENT_ID, clientId)
            .with(CLIENT_SECRET, clientSecret))
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(JsonNode.class)
    .map(tokenResponse -> tokenResponse.get(ACCESS_TOKEN).textValue())
    .cache(Duration.ofMinutes(30))
    .block();

  }
```